# Should we use the [poems] or [poetry] tag, and can we make one a synonym of the other?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Right now, this site has a [poems](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poems) tag and a [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag. Which tag should we use? I'm partial to [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), since the word "poetry" refers to the art form, while "poems" refers to poem in the plural.

Could we come to a consensus, and could we then make the tags synonyms of each other?

Comment: 'Poetry' is broader, just go with that.

Comment: I'll second `poetry`.

Comment: Syonym poems to poetry

Comment: Done, although a synonym is not needed. Synonyms were designed to equate  two complete different words with the same meaning (think 'cars' vs 'autos'). In this case, text completion will help guide the user to the right tag usage. `p` `o` `e` > `poetry`.

Comment: @Robert ... or `edgar-allan-poe`.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I would still recommend making [poems] a synonym of [poetry] (or blacklisting [poems]), [because even with the autocorrect, people are still asking questions with the \[poems\] tag](http://literature.stackexchange.com/revisions/491/1))

Comment: Hamlet, this is only a problem because the bar to create *new* tags is set artificially low during the private beta to bootstrap the system. Once the site is launched, it takes more experience with the site to create new tags. The occasional errant tag is easily corrected by the community.

Answer (score 2):

The [poems](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poems) tag has been merged into [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), which is now the only one remaining of the two.

As Robert noted in comments, synonymisation isn't an issue because typing `poe` into the tag box will lead users to [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) automatically anyway.

For discussion of the value of this tag, see [Is [poetry] too broad / how should we use the tag?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/413/17) and my own more recent [A proposal for [poetry] and [short-stories]](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/17).

<sub><sub>(I'm mainly posting this so that the question can have an accepted answer and not keep on getting bumped by Community.)</sub></sub>

Answer (score -1):

Just to reiterate the consensus that has already been arrived to in chat, we should only use [poetry]. That discussion occurred [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=34866939#34866939).

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it doesn't provide any reasoning for the conclusion. If you [edit] to add a summary of the arguments presented in that chat discussion, I'll reconsider my vote.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The discussion was pretty content-less with disagreement after statement of opinion, then one side said burninate and then people changed their minds.

Comment: Site policy is not decided in chat.

Comment: @Helmar When I get a chance I will add an argument