# Is [poetry] too broad / how should we use the tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) tag seems like it won't be a good fit here. It currently seems to be used on all questions about poems. This seems not good to me - it's like having a [books](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag.

**Should we burninate [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry), and if not, how should we use this tag?**

Comment: Whether a tag is applicable to too many questions to be useful is a valid question to raise, but asking whether it's a meta tag is probably leading you astray here (it isn't one). A tag *can be* a perfectly ordinary non-meta tag *and also* be too broadly applicable to be useful! On [rpg.se] we have ["rules" and "mechanics" blacklisted](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4949/1204), and they're not meta tags at all, they're just not useful for categorisation since they could easily apply to 90% of the site's questions.

Answer (score 6):

Following the [guideline from Meta.SE on burninating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate), I'd say keep it.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

   Yes, poetry is a clearly defined area of literature.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   I very much think so.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   I'd agree here too.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Haven't checked since we are already at 3 checks for keeping it.

Comment: Not sure if I'd agree on #3, since we're already using individual work tags. If a question is tagged [tag:the-raven], say, why would it need a [tag:poetry] tag *as well* since we'd already know it's about a poem?

Answer (score 4):

#### Should we burninate [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)? No. At least, not right now.

It is true that a [books](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) tag would be be redundant, but then poems, like novels, are often printed in books. I have a stack of them sitting beside me, waiting to be read (or re-read).

I would certainly use [poetry](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) as one of my favourite tags, so that I could find poetry questions of interest to me, so I think that such a tag would be useful. If we find that it is little-used, then we can burninate it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not I agree with your conclusion, but I certainly don't find your reasoning very compelling.